# Can I use demo open CTI controller for calls?

Tags: call-center

I found demo CTI controller: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI
Can I use it for real calls or it is only visual example? Will it work after changing settings (look at screenshot)? If it will not work where can I find information for building CTI adapter from scratch? [image: call center settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open CTI of salesforce only provide a softphone panel which is just a mediator between salesforce and any 3rd part service which provide all call center functionality like call, message, chat etc. With the help of open CTI you can only make changes in your softphone panel but if you want to make call you have to integrate your org with service providers like twilio.

You can found API here: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api

open CTI configuration
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI

Comment: I'm working with different service.Will I need to make some new code or will I only need to change settings of salesforce demo adapter?

Comment: So you have already integrated with different service provider API. Now what difficulties you are facing?

Comment: I use program on my computer to make calls. I want to make calls from salesforce without program.

Comment: No it is not possible now. In earlier version salesforce proved this facility but not its deprecated, so you have to write code to make call.